# Wrong result when integrating piecewise in sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I have been working with piecewise functions in sympy and it does not seem to be integrating them correctly with their context.

Piecewise function

[image: 1]

Correct Integration

[image: 2]

sympy output

[image: 3]

```
from sympy import *
init_printing(use_unicode=False, wrap_line=False)
x = Symbol('x')
f = Function('f')
a1 = 4
a2 = 8
a3 = 12
G = Piecewise((x,And(x<=a1,x>=0)),(4,And(x>a1,x<=a2)),((x-a3)**2/4,And(x>a2,x<=a3)))
diffeq1= Eq(f(x).diff(x),G)
gg1 = dsolve(diffeq1,f(x))
```

Am I missing something in my input concerning the creation of the piecewise function or in the differential equation solver?

Edit 2/24/2021

I have included an example of what g(x) would look like with the boundary condition of g(0)=0. Sympy used this boundary condition, with its answer describing the function as 4x between 4<x<8, which is almost there, but it doesn't include the context of what occurs at x = 4. What should occur is g(3.999) ~= g(4.0001), but instead sympy is saying g(3.999) ~= 8 and g(4.0001)~= 16.

[Numerically Integrated Method of f(x)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCxfo.png)

Comment: It is correct. In the second and third parts any constants from your "correct result" are absorbed into C2 and C3 in sympy. In fact, if someone were to ask me to integrate 4 wrt x, I'd come up with 4x + c, not 4(x - 4) + 8 + c.

Comment: But you are evaluating an "indefinite" integral from 0 to x for a piecewise function, and depending on where x lies, that will change the functions you are integrating and its context. Think about the area under this piecewise function up to x = 4. That is a known value, not some arbitrary constant that depends on boundary conditions. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1730049/is-the-indefinite-integral-of-a-piecewise-continuous-function-a-continuous-funct

Comment: Come again? Your correct result is also an indefinite integral, since it contains constants of integration. I don't understand what you're trying to say about the area under a graph, because the constant cancels out. Given the equations you gave to sympy, you got the right results. You need to explain why it should be what you claim it should be.

Comment: I appreciate your assistance. I will try to demonstrate graphically what is wrong. For now, consider this: If I set initial conditions such that g(0) = 0, sympy will answer that the arbritary Constant is equal to 0, and the function can be described by 4x from 4<x<=8, which is incorrect. g(3.999) should be close to g(4.0001), but sympy's outputs are not reflecting that.